# Error Using ImageSearch's *n variation

Tags: autohotkey

```
CoordMode Mouse
CoordMode Pixel

FindAndClick(ImgName,accept) ;simple function to click on given image with a given variation
{
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %ImgName%.png, *%accept%
    if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        MsgBox error searching: %A_WorkingDir%\%ImgName%.png *%accept%
    else if (not ErrorLevel = 1)
    {
        MouseMove, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
        Click
    }
}

FindAndClick("test",5)
```

Expected output: For it to just click on the img if it's on screen.

Actual output: MsgBox error searching: ahkbot\test.png *5

The code works perfectly fine if I completely remove the accept variable but I need a way to change the variation tolerance.

My guesses as to what might be wrong:

1. I just don't know how to properly format the *n in ImageSearch correctly ?
2. it is reading %accept% as a string instead of an integer ?

Thanks for any help. I'm really new to AHK so I feel like this should be an easy answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, just had to flip the var and file location

```
CoordMode Mouse
CoordMode Pixel

FindAndClick(ImgName,accept) ;simple function to click on given image with a given variation
{
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, *%accept%, A_ScreenHeight, %ImgName%.png 
    if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        MsgBox error searching: %A_WorkingDir%\%ImgName%.png *%accept%
    else if (not ErrorLevel = 1)
    {
        MouseMove, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
        Click
    }
}

FindAndClick("test",5)
```